# python numpy vector math

Tags: python, numpy

What is the `numpy` equivalent to [`euclid`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/euclid)'s 2d vector classes / operations ?  ( like: `euclid.Vector2` )

So far I have this. Create two vectors

```
import numpy as np

loc = np.array([100., 100.])
vel = np.array([30., 10])

loc += vel

# reseting speed to a default value, maintaining direction
vel.normalize()
vel *= 200

loc += vel
```

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you're doing is pretty standard.

Comment: One thing to look out for is multiplication of arrays. Numpy array multiply by element. If you want to multiply two vectors, use the `dot()` method.

Comment: Judging by the comments and the answer, I think people completely misunderstood your question, and didn't realize you're talking about replacing the `euclid` module.

Comment: By the way, how was the migration? Was it motivated by performance? I'm planning on use `euclid`, so any tips are welcome :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can just use numpy arrays. Look at the [numpy for matlab users](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) page for a detailed overview of the pros and cons of arrays w.r.t. matrices.

As I mentioned in the comment, having to use the `dot()` function or method for mutiplication of vectors is the biggest pitfall. But then again, numpy arrays are *consistent*. All operations are element-wise. So adding or subtracting arrays and multiplication with a scalar all work as expected of vectors.

**Edit2:** Starting with Python 3.5 and numpy 1.10 you can use the `@` infix-operator for matrix multiplication, thanks to [pep 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

**Edit:** Regarding your comment:

1. Yes. The whole of numpy is based on arrays.
2. Yes. `linalg.norm(v)` is a good way to get the length of a vector. But what you get depends on the  possible second argument to norm! Read the docs.
3. To normalize a vector, just divide it by the length you calculated in (2). Division of arrays by a scalar is also element-wise.

   An example in ipython:

   ```
   In [1]: import math

   In [2]: import numpy as np

   In [3]: a = np.array([4,2,7])

   In [4]: np.linalg.norm(a)
   Out[4]: 8.3066238629180749

   In [5]: math.sqrt(sum([n**2 for n in a]))
   Out[5]: 8.306623862918075

   In [6]: b = a/np.linalg.norm(a)

   In [7]: np.linalg.norm(b)
   Out[7]: 1.0
   ```

   Note that `In [5]` is an alternative way to calculate the length. `In [6]` shows normalizing the vector.

Comment: [1] Is this the common route to use? (Using numpy.array vs euclid or something else) [2] to get `Vector2.magnitude()` do I use `linalg.norm(v)` [3] What function do I use for `Vector2.normalize()` ?